# How can I extract the information I need from a tkinter button function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hello I am trying to make a GUI that will read a pdf and extract the information within it so I can use it later on. My issue is I save all of the information from the PDF into a dictionary but I know I can't use a return statement in a tkinter button so I am stuck on how to use that dictionary again later on in my program. I tried to use a global variable but that didn't work for me either, I must have done it incorrectly. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from tkinter import filedialog
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
import json

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")
root.title("Test")

filtered_data = {}

def openFile():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pdfobject = open(filepath,'rb')
    pdf = pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdfobject)
    with open('info.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(pdf.getFormTextFields(), indent=5))
        file.close()
    files = "info.json"
    with open(files, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for key, value in data.items():
            if value != None:
                filtered_data[key] = value

btn2 = Button(root, text="Open File", command=openFile).pack()

print(filtered_data)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show what you have tried on using global variable.

Comment: Hello, I edited my code with how I tried to set up the global variable, I set it at the top of my function and removed where I initialized it lower in my code. When I tried this I could still not print my dictionary outside of my function.

Comment: You cannot initialize the variable in the line `global filtered_data = {}`. Also the variable will be created *after* `openFile()` has been executed.

Comment: I tried to initialize a global dictionary outside of my function in my new code, and then I am appending to it within my function but when I print it outside of the function I am getting an empty dictionary, do I need to put global (dictionary name) within my function?

Comment: You called `print(filtered_data)` before `openFile()` is executed, so why do you expect it show something?

Comment: I am very new to python, I was thinking if my print statement was at the bottom it would be ran last. How would I be able to print my dict after I have appended everything to it if the function is only called when they click the button? Should I do an if statement like if the button is clicked print my dict?

Comment: To test it, you can create another function to show the content of `filtered_data` and create another button to call that function when it is clicked.